# How do I use mixins in Sass using the indented (old style) syntax?

Tags: sass

My Sass (indented syntax) looks like this:

```
.wrapper
    overflow: hidden
    overflow: hidden
    width: 100%
    height: 100%

.hide_menu
    @mixin transition($properties: all, $duration: 0.2s, $easing: ease-in-out)
        -webkit-transition: $property $duration $easing
        -moz-transition: $property $duration $easing
        -ms-transition: $property $duration $easing
        -o-transition: $property $duration $easing
        transition: $property $duration $easing
    @mixin transform($translate: 0 0)
        -webkit-transform: $translate
        -moz-transform: $translate
        -ms-transform: $translate
        -o-transform: $translate
        transform: $translate
    @mixin transform($translate3d: 275px 0 0)
        -webkit-transform: $translate3d
        -moz-transform: $translate3d
        -ms-transform: $translate3d
        -o-transform: $translate3d
        transform: $translate3d

nav 
    width: 275px
    height: 100%
    position: fixed
    top: 0
    left: 0
```

But when I compile it, the contents of my mixins do not appear in the CSS.

Comment: Do you mean once you compile to straight CSS? It's a mixin, if it hasn't been applied to any rule, it won't show up. You need to apply it to something, e.g. `body a { @include transform(); }`

Comment: no i did apply, it's under .hide_menu

Comment: Then your issue is probably that you forgot your `{}`s and your `;`s.

Comment: Start learning about Grunt and start using Auto-prefixer. Here is a good article for it. css-tricks.com/autoprefixer/

Comment: so after add the mixin at the begin of the sass file should i also add under the class {@include transform();} right?

Comment: There is not enough code here to reproduce your problem.  We need to be able to take your code and compile it to see the exact results you see.  Otherwise it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @Lbezerra so your rule looks like: `.hide_menu { @include transform(); }` ?

Comment: Umm, did you find a solution? Could you perhaps be confusing SASS with SCSS? To me, it looks like your syntax is wrong for both (you have some syntax of one, and some syntax of the other) ...

Comment: yes i did found the solution, i have to put the mixin on the top of the file, and the first line would be the place i should add any value and make that as a default, after that i can just add on the element a @include command, also must be saved as .scss format and the compass will compile for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you've only *defined* the mixin, not actually invoked it.  If you want to call the mixin, you must use the proper syntax:

```
.foo
    +transform($translate3d: 275px 0 0)
```

Also, if you plan on reusing your mixins elsewhere, you should place them at the root level.  Where they are now, they can only be seen inside that particular instance of your .hide_menu class.